# How to show order section list in UItableView using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the data from `JSON` with help of `Codable` and loading into `TableView`. Here, JSON `multiple array` I am receiving, every array have different key name. The key name I am showing into tableview on `section`. Now, the problem is JSON array showing proper order list but due to `dictionary` storage I am getting `unordered` list in tableview result. I need to show same `order` which is JSON showing.

**Codable**

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let status : Bool
    let sections : [Section]

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case status, data }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .status)
        let data = try container.decode([String:[Result]].self, forKey: .data)
        //sections = data.map{ Section(title: $0.key, result: $0.value) }
        sections = data.compactMap{ return $0.value.isEmpty ? nil : Section(title: $0.key, result: $0.value) }
    }
}

struct Section {
    let title : String
    var result : [Result]
}

struct Result : Decodable {
    let id, name, date : String
    let group : [String]
}
```

**Tableview**

```
// MARK: UITableview Delegates

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return isFiltering ? filteredSections.count : sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let currentSection = isFiltering ? filteredSections[section] : sections[section]
    return currentSection.result.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return isFiltering ? filteredSections[section].title : sections[section].title
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell
    let section = isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section]
    let item = section.result[indexPath.row]
    cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //print("You tapped cell number \(indexPath.row).")
    let section = isFiltering ? filteredSections[indexPath.section] : sections[indexPath.section]
    let item = section.result[indexPath.row]
    print("\(item)")
}
```

Comment: Your structure doesn't accurately represent your json. It seems that it isn't an arbitrary dictionary, you have an array of "overdue" items, "today" items etc. you should decode those specific arrays into specific properties and then create a computed variable that returns the sections

Comment: I see three solutions:
1) Edit your API and get an array of objects
2) Add another object to your response that states the order of the keys so you can sort them in your TableView
3) Add an array of strings in your app in order to sort the dictionary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sort the keys but you can define the key order

```
let keyOrder = ["Overdue", "Today", "Tomorrow", "Nextweek", "Future"]

struct Root : Decodable {
    let status : Bool
    let sections : [Section]

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case status, data }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        status = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .status)
        let data = try container.decode([String:[Result]].self, forKey: .data)
        sections = keyOrder.compactMap({ key -> Section? in
            guard let section = data[key], !section.isEmpty else { return nil }
            return Section(title: key, result: section)
        })
    }
}
```

Your table view datasource and delegate methods look pretty familiar

Comment: Thanks. The above solution looks hardcoded array values. If we change anything names in server side then it may occur crash or I need to change again into hardcoded array. So, please anything alternative solutions?

Comment: The sort order is completely arbitrary. If you are responsible for the backend send something along with the keys which can be sorted for example an index.

Comment: Thanks. I changed index in server side  and completed proper sorting